# Actual In-App purchases not reflected in App Store Connect dashboard

Tags: in-app-purchase

I currently have 4 in-app purchases that are available in my app. I can see in last month's financial report that all 4 of them have been purchased recently.

However, this doesn't match what I can see in the App Store Connect Dashboard. I go to my app and then click into *In-App purchases* (under Features heading). It only lists 2 products as approved.

I did prepare some changes to the in-app purchases last year, but didn't at the time release a new version. I can't remember quite what I did, but I really just want the Dashboard in-app purchases to reflect how things actually are right now (4 products).

I'm about to release a new app version, but am afraid that two of the current in-app purchase options will then no longer be available.

I tried adding back the current purchase options, but get an error that the product id is already being used. Yes, I know! So show me that in the list. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

In case others have the same issue:

It turns out that two of the purchases were set up as in-app purchases and the other two as non-renewing subscriptions.

To see if there are any subscriptions, it's not enough to just click Subscriptions. You also have to click Manage subscriptions to see if there are any.